# Images are shown in new row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to upload images with preview.
That is working properly.
problem is images are showing one by one in each row. I want to show images in one row and the close sign should show in upper right at image and should display on hover.

I tried it [jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/m51wbb9c/](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/m51wbb9c/)

How to achive this.

The javascript:

```
 $("i#dzopen").dropzone({
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 10,
 url: 'http://www.example.com/UploadImages',
    previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    maxFiles: 20,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            alert("again");
            console.log("log "+responseText);
            $.each(responseText, function(k, v) {
                console.log("l path " + v.largePicPath);
                console.log("s path " + v.smallPicPath);
                console.log("height " + v.imgHeight + " wid " + v.imgWidth);
            });
            console.log(file);
            alert('uploded ' + file.name);
   
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question itself. If JSFiddle is inaccessible this question will become completely worthless.

Comment: I have included external css library I dont know which part to include here. So I added in fiddle

Comment: With the code you've now included your question is even more confusing. You've tagged this as HTML and CSS, yet the only code you've included is a jQuery snippet which appears to use a plugin you've not even mentioned. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I find it is css specific problem I am using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/3.12.0/css/basic.css this css.

Comment: Something hosted on smsiland.com is stopping JSFiddle from loading

Answer (score 0):

Consider using *float*

When you enable float (with choices of left, right and none), it'll have all the images in one line.

So, your html can be:

```
<img src="blah.gif" class="float_img" />
```

Your CSS would have something like this:

```
.float_img {
float:left;
}
```

That'll solve the problem you stated in the title

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
 .float_left{
   float:left;
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
 }
.float_left:hover > a.close{display:block;}

a.close{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
}

</style>



</head>
<body>
<!--first image panel-->
<div class="float_left">
  <img src="sourceOfImage" />
  <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
</div>

<!--second image panel-->
<div class="float_left">
   <img src="sourceOfImage" />
   <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```